# Powershell : Get directory permission recursively

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the CSV output like below so that user can filter in excel.

Folder,Group,Permission
I:\Folder1,corp\group1,ReadData,ExecuteFile,Synchronize
I:\Folder1\Folder2,corp\group2,ReadData,ExecuteFile,Synchronize

Below is what is started with. Very inefficient and does not give the desired CSV output. Will appreciate any help.

```
$output_file = $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss)+'.txt'
"{0},{1},{2}" -f "Folder","Groups","Permissions"| add-content -path $output_file


$file_content = ''

function GetFolders($path = $pwd)
{
    if( $path -ne $null) {
        $new_row = Get-ACL $path | select -ExpandProperty Access | Where-Object IdentityReference -Like "CORP*" | SELECT $path, IdentityReference, FileSystemRights | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
        $fileContent += $new_row
        $fileContent | add-content -path $output_file

        foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
        {
           if (Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container)
           {
                Write-Output $item.FullName
                GetFolders $item.FullName
                $new_row = Get-ACL $item.FullName | select -ExpandProperty Access | Where-Object IdentityReference -Like "CORP*" | SELECT $item.FullName, IdentityReference, FileSystemRights | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
                $fileContent += $new_row
                $fileContent | add-content -path $output_file
           }
        }
    }
}


GetFolders "J:\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path but went off-course a bit.

```
Set-Content -Path $FileName -Value 'Folder,Groups,Permissions'

(Get-Acl -Path $Path).Access |
  Where-Object -Property IdentityReference -like 'corp*' |
  ForEach-Object {
      Add-Content -Path $FileName -Value "$Path,$($_.IdentityReference),$($_.FileSystemRights -replace '\s')"
  }
```

---

To be a little more fancy (if you want to edit the code in the subexpressions or something of that nature)

```
$Val = {"$Path,$($_.IdentityReference),$($_.FileSystemRights -replace '\s')"}
... -Value (&$Val) ...
```

Comment: I don't get why you're using `Add-Content` instead of `Export-Csv`

Comment: Both are valid, but if the data is already formed, then `Add-Content` is less overhead. @Clijsters

Comment: Sure, but it's also slower, isn't it? I think it depends on hardware, but opening and closing a stream on every iteration sounds heavy. But yeah, the less overhead results in a very clear and simple code example.